# How do you plot scatter graph with chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to figure out how to plot a scatter graph with chart.js the data I am trying to plot is randomly generated where `dates` is a list of `datetime.now()` objects and `prices` is a list of float numbers

```
dates = [datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")  for i in range(10)]
```

```
var dates_ = {{dates|tojson}}
var prices_ = {{prices|tojson}}
function parse_data(dates , prices)
{
    console.log(dates.length , prices.length)
    var tmp = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++)
    {
        var x;
        var y;
        tmp[i] = {x: dates.at(i), y: prices.at(i)};
    }
    return tmp;
}
var data_ = parse_data(dates_, prices_);

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
        lablel: "some_data",
        data: data_}]
});
```

converting the dates to float numbers does the job but it shows the dates as number and it is not that good looking

Comment: You should define the x-axis as a time axis as described here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html and https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/time-line.html

Comment: @uminder can you explain how to do it with scatter and lot line I am struggling here

Comment: please provide a runnable sample (e.g. StackBlitz) and me or something else can help you find the missing part.

Comment: @uminder [example](https://jsfiddle.net/du0Lmw38/)  when i use scatter the graph is empty but when i choose line i can see the data

Comment: You can just use a line chart and in the dataset set the `showLine` option to false

Comment: @LeeLenalee I think that solved my problem but can you write your own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scatter chart uses a line chart internally but changes it so the `showLine` property becomes false and both axis are set to linear.

So you can just set the `showLine` property to false in your dataset and use a line chart.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your x-axis as follows

```
x: {      
  type: 'time',
  time: {
    parser: 'YYYY-M-D',
    unit: 'day',
    displayFormats: {
      day: 'D MMM YYYY'
    },
    tooltipFormat: 'D MMM YYYY'
  }
}
```

> Further information can be found at the Chart.js documentation [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html) and in the Chart.js samples [here](http://chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/time-line.html).

> Note that I use [chartjs-adapter-moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-adapter-moment) together with [moment](https://momentjs.com/) to make this work. The formats for parsing and displaying time values as desired can be found [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
var test = [
  { x: "2022-1-8", y: 950 },
  { x: "2022-1-9", y: 1100 },
  { x: "2022-1-10", y: 990 },
  { x: "2022-1-12", y: 1250 },
  { x: "2022-1-13", y: 1050 }
];

var chart = new Chart('chart-line', {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: test,
      label: 'buys',
      borderColor: "#3e95cd"
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    scales: {
      x: {      
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          parser: 'YYYY-M-D',
          unit: 'day',
          displayFormats: {
            day: 'D MMM YYYY'
          },
          tooltipFormat: 'D MMM YYYY'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@1.0.0"></script>
<canvas id="chart-line" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: I copied the code but got an error in the console `check that a complete adapter is provided`

Comment: Make sure, to include the `chartjs-adapter-moment` and `moment` library

Comment: I did still showing an error

Comment: in the console i get this warning `DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE`

Comment: For me, it also works in your amended [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3f912jq4/) but I don't know about your development environment. It may be worth posting a new question for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {
  labels: ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Dataset 1',
    data: [{x:1, y:12}, {x:2, y:3}, {x:3, y:2}, {x:4, y:1}, {x:5, y:8}, {x:6, y:8}, {x:7, y:2}, {x:8, y:2}, {x:9, y:3}, {x:10, y:5}, {x:11, y:7}, {x:12, y:1}]
  }]
}

const config = {
  type: 'scatter',
  data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
  },
}

const $canvas = document.getElementById('chart')
const chart = new Chart($canvas, config)
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="width: 98vw; height:180px">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js"></script>
```